# How to install boost c++ libraries in OSX

Tags: c++, macos, boost, installation

I downloaded boostjam and put it in with the install files and tried to run it, the following error is displayed:

> error: error: no Jamfile in current
>   directory found, and no target
>   references specified.

Comment: ‘It doesn’t work’ is too vague a description. What exactly doesn’t work? What error messages do you get? Try providing a more detailed description of your problem.

Answer (score 20):

The more modern package manager [homebrew](http://brew.sh) does this with a single

```
$ brew install boost
```

Answer (score 4):

If you first install [MacPorts](http://www.macports.org/), you can install Boost with a single command:

```
sudo port install boost
```

Comment: +1 I normally use this too but it can sometimes lag behind if one needs the current and latest release all the time.

Comment: They've been pretty good about keeping it up to date recently. It seems like the last few versions were available a few weeks after the official release.

Comment: cool. thanks Ferruccio. I prefer MacPorts too as I don't have to worry about the downloads, commands and such like. Will probably revert back to MacPorts soon as it makes life really really  easy

Answer (score 3):

Did you download boost archive and unpack it? Why you downloaded bjam? What install files? Bootstrap can compile bjam on your computer. Short story howto install:

1. Unpack the boost archive to desktop
2. Navigate with terminal to boost directory (its something like /users/zbuffer/desktop/boost_1_46_1)
3. type:
4. ./bootstrap.sh
5. pay attention to error messages
6. if bootstrap may not execute and you need to allow it before:
7. chmod +x bootstrap.sh
8. if bootstrap worked type:
9. ./bjam architecture=combined
10. pay attention to error messages

If something is still wrong and you come back to ask here around then please write what exactly you did and at what step what happened.

Comment: It successfully created the files, but they exist in a directory in my download directory. I don't think this is the right place to put them. Where should they be?

Comment: ./bjam architecture=combined address-model=32_64 to get 32 and 64 bit support just in case you need them.

Answer (score 0):

I found [this link](http://www.technoboria.com/2009/12/compiling-boost-on-mac-os-x-for-64bit-builds/) helpful. I ended up having to use the following command to ensure 64 bit support as well which I need

```
./bjam architecture=combined address-model=32_64
```

Answer (score 0):

In order to avoid troubles compiling third party libraries that need boost installed in your system, run this:

```
sudo port install boost +universal
```