# how do i install boost on my mac?

Tags: c++, boost

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to install boost c++ libraries in OSX](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5797443/how-to-install-boost-c-libraries-in-osx)

I want to use boost to serialize some objects in my game, but I got stuck when I wanted to use boost.
So I have downloaded and unzipped boost into a dir.

Now what?

Comment: To compile anything in Boost, you need a directory containing the boost/ subdirectory in your #include path. What is my include path? and where?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You might use macports which simplifies the installation of boost significantly.

1. Download macports from http://www.macports.org/
2. Run `sudo port install boost`
   This will download an install boost automatically. And also install all dependencies of boost.
3. Wait until boost is compiled. Takes about 0.5h on my macbook pro.
4. Your boost library is then found at `/opt/local/include/boost`

Comment: I'll try that. Well couln't I just move my sub folder "boost" into that location then?

Comment: No certain libraries needs to be compiled. So you need to compile boost. However with macports everything runs automatically such that you do not need to think about what is happening, just enjoy boost in the end :) And do not mess around in the macports folder, as this might induce side effects.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you should just try and follow the [Boost Getting Started Guide](http://www.boost.org/more/getting_started/index.html).

Start reading [Getting Started on Unix variants (e.g. Linux, MacOS)](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_51_0/more/getting_started/unix-variants.html), it should be a gentle yet complete introduction.

Comment: yes i am doing that now, but i simply don't understand everything they say hehe. To compile anything in Boost, you need a directory containing the boost/ subdirectory in your #include path. that line i got lost

Comment: I think it is telling you that, to use Boost in your program, you have to include `boost/something`, not just `something`.